# sbt plugin dependency not resolved from nexus - Server access Error: Connection timed out

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, nexus

I have a Play Framework project (v2.5.3) using sbt v0.13.11. I have installed the latest version of sbt 1.1.0 (do I need to install an older version?). I have also installed the latest version of Intellij 2017.3. We are using a corporate nexus server to resolve sbt dependencies.

My repositories file is set up like so:

```
[repositories]  
local  
my-ivy-proxy-releases:http://nexus.xxx.com:8081/nexus/repository/ivy-releases/[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]  
my-maven-proxy-releases:http://nexus.xxx.com:8081/nexus/repository/mvn-repositories/
```

I have set an environment variable:

```
SBT_OPTS = -Dsbt.override.build.repos = true
```

When I load the project in Intellij the sbt refresh gets stuck resolving dependencies from the sbt-uglify plugin. I know it is sbt-uglify because I commented out all the plugins to figure out which one is the issue.

plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.3")  
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")  
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")  
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")  
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.9")  
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.3")  
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")  
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.2")  
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-uglify" % "2.0.0")
```

Here are the errors/warnings I get in Intellij:

```
[info] Resolving org.webjars.npm#right-align;[0.1.1,0.2) ...  
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect  
url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.webjars.npm/right-align/
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect  
url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.webjars.npm/right-align/  
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect 
url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/npm/right-align/maven-metadata.xml  
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect  
url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/npm/right-align/
[warn] problem while listing resources in http://nexus.xxx.com:8081/nexus/repository/ivy-releases/org.webjars.npm/right-align/ with my-ivy-proxy-releases:
[warn]   java.lang.NullPointerException charsetName
```

It takes about an hour to fully resolve everything because it will try to resolve dependencies for about 10 different org.webjars.npm libraries and try 4 different urls timing out each time. Note that the project does not fail to compile. It eventually pulls the libraries from our nexus but only after timing out the other urls. If I `sbt clean compile` on the command prompt I still get the warnings but it takes less time to resolve (maybe a few minutes).

Installing node.js (the compiler was complaining it couldn't find a js engine) temporarily resolved the issue until there is a change in build.sbt and it has to refresh the project.

Questions are as follows:
1. Why does it take much longer to resolve in Intellij vs command prompt?
2. Why is sbt not hitting the nexus repository first?
3. Is it possible to get rid of the errors/warnings or at least reduce the timeout?

Comment: Looks like there is similar issue on SBT tracker: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2243